# Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata - Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We are trying to consume the broker messages in Kafka hosted in Windows standalone.
Consumer is running in Kubernetes.

**server.properties:**

listeners=PLAINTEXT://:29092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://myhostname:29092
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

**Consumer Error:**

[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka startTimeMs: 1627883198273
[main] INFO XXX.XXX.KafkaConsumerProperties - Kafka Topic Name : table-update
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=consumer-GroupConsumer-1, groupId=GroupConsumer] **Subscribed to topic(s): table-update**
[main] INFO XX.XX.XXXXX- Could not run Loader: **Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata** .

Consumer config values :

```
        allow.auto.create.topics = true
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        auto.offset.reset = earliest
        bootstrap.servers = [myhostname:29092]
        check.crcs = true
        client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
        client.id = consumer-GroupConsumer-1
        client.rack = 
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
        enable.auto.commit = false
        exclude.internal.topics = true
        fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
        fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
        fetch.min.bytes = 1
        group.id = GroupConsumer
        group.instance.id = null
        heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
        interceptor.classes = []
        internal.leave.group.on.close = true
        internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
        isolation.level = read_uncommitted
        key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        max.partition.fetch.bytes = 52428800
        max.poll.interval.ms = 2147483647
        max.poll.records = 1000
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 120000
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        session.timeout.ms = 60000
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.engine.factory.class = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        value.deserializer = XXXX
```

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Why is the consumer running in k8s, but not the broker? Sounds like you're missing some network bridging

Answer (score 0):

While fetching the metadata for topics there are possibilities of multiple error conditions like invalid topic name, metadata leader, offline partitions etc. You can get more info about the errors by logging at debug level. The debug level logs the error condition

```
log.debug("Topic metadata fetch included errors: {}", errors);
```